# There is a problem with my previous character positions in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working to a JS game where I have a player named Ronin and the game is something like a 2d platformer. I worked on canvas to make him and I made him move x pixels to left/ right at keys A/D onkeydown. The problem is that I can't erase his 'copies' (previous positions of the character that now should dissapear). I would not want to use ctx.clearRect(), so please give me another solution.
Thanks in advance!

[WalkLeft1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0BfH.jpg)------[WalkLeft2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF1gt.jpg)------[WalkRight1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wac0x.jpg)------[WalkRight2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLxos.jpg)

```js
/* Walk Left/Right 1/2 in the description no matter with the'broken' state file, it's because it can't draw a file that he does not know :) */
/* ------------------------------------------ */
/* files in my directory:

index.html
style.css
script.js
Costumes >
        WalkLeft >
                  WalkLeft1.jpg
                  WalkLeft2.jpg
        WalkRight >
                  WalkRight1.jpg
                  WalkRight2.jpg

*/

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


Scene = function () {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = canvas.width;
    this.h = canvas.height;
    this.style = {
        fillStyle: "white",
        strokeStyle: "red",
        lineWidth: 5,
    }
    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.style.fillStyle;
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.style.strokeStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = this.style.lineWidth;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
}
Character = function () {
    this.width = 77;
    this.height = 92;
    this.x = 10;
    this.vx = 20;
    this.padding = 10;
    this.y = canvas.height - this.height - 10;
    this.img0 = document.getElementById("img0");
    this.img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    this.img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
    this.img3 = document.getElementById("img3");
    this.counter = {
        walkLeft: 0,
        walkRight: 0,
    };
    this.draw = {
        walkLeft: () => {
            if (this.counter.walkLeft == 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.img0, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.counter.walkLeft = 1;
            } else if (this.counter.walkLeft == 1) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.img1, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.counter.walkLeft = 0;
            }
        },
        walkRight: () => {
            if (this.counter.walkRight == 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.img2, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.counter.walkRight = 1;
            } else if (this.counter.walkRight == 1) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.img3, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.counter.walkRight = 0;
            }
        }
    };

}
const scene = new Scene();
scene.draw();


var player = new Character();

var initInterval = setInterval(
    function () {
        player.draw.walkRight();
    }, 400
);

var currentInterval = undefined;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key == "a" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        if (initInterval) {
            clearInterval(initInterval);
            initInterval = undefined;
        }
        if (currentInterval) {
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            currentInterval = undefined;
        }
        setTimeout( // for first 300ms delay onchange
            function () {
                player.draw.walkLeft();
            }, 1);
            if(player.x - player.vx > player.padding) {
                player.x -= player.vx;
            } else {
                player.x = player.padding;
            }
        currentInterval = setInterval(
            function () {
                player.draw.walkLeft();
            }, 300);
            
    }
    if (e.key == "d" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        if (initInterval) {
            clearInterval(initInterval);
            initInterval = undefined;
        }
        if (currentInterval) {
            clearInterval(currentInterval);
            currentInterval = undefined;
        }
        setTimeout( // for first 300ms delay onchange
            function () {
                player.draw.walkRight();
            }, 1);
            if(player.x + player.vx < canvas.width - player.padding) {
                player.x += player.vx;
            } else {
                player.x = canvas.width - player.padding;
            }
        currentInterval = setInterval(
            function () {
                player.draw.walkRight();
            }, 300);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="images">
            <img id="img0" width="77px" height="92px" src="Costumes\WalkLeft\WalkLeft1.jpg" />
            <img id="img1" width="77px" height="92px" src="Costumes\WalkLeft\WalkLeft2.jpg" />
            <img id="img2" width="77px" height="92px" src="Costumes\WalkRight\WalkRight1.jpg" />
            <img id="img3" width="77px" height="92px" src="Costumes\WalkRight\WalkRight2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to explain why you don't want to use the only proper solution, namely `ctx.clearRect()`

Comment: Because I actually would want to use background Scene images & enemies & stuff and clearRect would erase them all just to change the frame, which is not worth

Comment: I initially thought about something with requestAnimationFrame but I don't know to use it properly

Comment: The only solution that comes in my mind is that I sould use 2 canvases: one only with the player and one with other things .... But what about enemies????!

Comment: Pretty much any game (and app) in existence redraws the entire screen (here: canvas) 30 or 40 or 60 times per second. That's simply how it works. You use `requestAnimationFrame` to call your drawing function each frame, and it draws the background, then enemies, stuff and the player.

Comment: problem is that i do not know to use it properly, so best i would need an ex, because i don't get the mdn stuff :)

Comment: an applicable example in THIS situation

Comment: Here's a basic canvas "animation" example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yno8a45w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work in layers. You put your background layer images in one canvas, your character and enemies in another, then copy the contents of each layer starting from the back, in order, onto a 'buffer' canvas. once that's done, you copy the result onto the visible on-screen canvas. Throw away the buffer (or clear it) at the end of each loop.

If a layer doesn't change, just keep it; if it does, create a new canvas for each frame (or clear the canvas you used). You can create as many layers as you like this way (or as many as you've got memory).

Comment: I finally solved the problem by making the canvas scene static and the player to reset every 1 milisecond ( to make the 'copy' dissapear extremely fast ). Thanks for your answer and it is very probably to use it in the 'enemy' section! Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark it as the answer! 